# Remove "mailto:" from javascript variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove the `mailto:` from a javascript variable which containts the href attribute of an a element:

```
 var email = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

The output should just be the email address. I try to append the address to a div element:

```
$(this).append(email);
```

Comment: Please use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var email = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
 var address = email.split('mailto:')[1];

 //Append to div
 $('#divId').append(address);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove the "mailto:" prefix from the string inside `email` variable, using `substring` method:

```js
var emailRef = 'mailto:name@email.com';
// Get the substring starting from the 7th character to the end of the string
var email = emailRef.substring(7);

console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the basis of `:` present in `href`

```js
var email = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
var onlyEmail = email.split(":")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, it's just [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

```
"mailto:foo@example.com?subject=Hi"
    .replace(/^mailto:([^?]+).*/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it. As simple as
`(this).append(email.replace("mailto:","");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
$.each( email, function( key, value ) {
//check for mailto
 if (value.startsWith('mailto:')){
   //Append to div
   $(this).append(address);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this as:

```
var email = $(this).find('a').attr('href').split(':')[1]; // gives you email
```

Here `.split(':')` will split the string at the index of `:` and returns an array then you can take the `[1]` first index to get the email.

For a demo:

```js
var email = $('a').attr('href').split(':')[1];
console.log(email);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">Get the mail of this anchor.</a>
```